# Writing to Bigquery with Spark: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery, spark-streaming

I'm new at spark and I'm trying to develop a new project which is collecting data from Kafka and processing it with spark. After that it has to write in Bigquery but I encountered a problem. Everything is fine but when the spark starts to write stream data It fails because of the **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 9: gs://[gs:/-bucketname-/.spark-bigquery-application_1658471270896_0034-3c5412b9-1de4-471c-a67f-9711ac08abe2.** I couldn't figure it out how I solve this.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger.ProcessingTime

val bucket = "[gs://idsa-st]"
spark.conf.set("temporaryGcsBucket", bucket)
spark.conf.set("parentProject", "apt-federation-350820")

val kafkaDF = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092").option("subscribe","spark-exp").load
val schema = StructType(List(StructField("ProductKey",IntegerType),StructField("ProductName",StringType),StructField("ProductCategory",StringType),StructField("ProductPrice",IntegerType),StructField("TimeStamp",LongType),StructField("CustomerID",IntegerType)))
val activationDF = kafkaDF.select(from_json($"value".cast("string"),schema).alias("activation"))
val sortedModelCountDF = activationDF.groupBy($"activation"("ProductName"),$"activation"("CustomerID"),$"activation"("TimeStamp")).count.sort($"count".desc)
val sortedModelCountQuery = sortedModelCountDF.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("bigquery").option("table","project.output").option("checkpointLocation", "gs://spark-st/").option("failOnDataLoss",false).option("truncate",false).trigger(ProcessingTime("5 seconds")).start
```

And I started spark-shell with these packages

```
spark-shell  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 --jars=gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz5N2.png)

Comment: I suspect that you should strip the `gs://` part and the brackets from the bucket name.

Comment: Agree with @Jasper-M. A closer look to the error description shows that spark already surrounds the value with “gs://[..]”. And the fact that at the end of the bucket name, there is “%5D” which is basically url encoded for closing brackets.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but now writeStream is not starting. I don't know what should I do. I think there is a mistake in the connection.

Comment: @samitugal Have you read the documentations of spark about this particular scenario?

Comment: Yes, I have read it. Finally, I found my mistake and It worked successfully thank you so much. You are a lifesaver.